# using Action Script 3 remove an object that appeared in the run time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I use this code to create list of words  from an array and make them act like buttons
in the main page i have 2 buttons that activate the for loop to create the list of words
the problem is when i hit the second button in the main the list of words of the first button still shown on the screen, i need to remove the list first then activate the second loop
i used the `removeChildAt()` function but it didn't worked
what should i do ?

```
var words:Array = [];
var word:MovieClip=new MovieClip();

if(e.target.name=="glossumbolA"){

words=['School1','School2','School3','School4','School5','School6']

for (var j:int = 0; j < words.length; j++)
{
    word = createTextButton(words[j]);
        addChild(word);
    word.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wordButtonClick);
}
}



else if(e.target.name=="glossumbolB"){

words=['Class1','Class2']

for (var i:int = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{

     word = createTextButton(words[i]);
     addChild(word);
     word.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wordButtonClick);
}

    }


function createTextButton(){

//code to make the word in the array a button

}

function wordButtonClick(){

//code to make an action when the word in the array clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple ways to do that: 
1. create one new MovieClip inside 'word' (with name A), for glossumbolA and one new for glossumbolB (with name B), create buttons inside MCs. You can set 'visible' true || false for A and B. If glossumbolA button is clicked - check if B is visible, set visible to 0.
or
 `while (word.numChildren > 0) {
    word.removeChildAt(0);
}` then create new buttons

Comment: thank you for the feed back, the second way didn't worked as it keeps removing the last movie clip only and the previous five keep shown in the screen,,,,

school6 only which is removed,,,,

the first way , how could i put the words as buttons in another movie clip ?

Comment: 'var wordA:MovieClip=new MovieClip(); word.addChild(wordA);' as an example